# NSURLConnection delay leads to an empty UItableViewCell without the picture

Tags: ios, xcode, asynchronous, uitableview, nsurlconnection

My app downloads the user's Facebook profile picture with an asynchronous (NSURLConnection) connection so that it can display the profile picture on a customized UITableViewCell. The problem is; the customized tableViewCell is created before the picture gets downloaded so the delay leads to an empty tableViewCell without the picture. How can I solve this problem?

My approach is to reach each cell by using a (for-in enumeration) and (a tag for each cell) in "connectionDidFinishLoading" method.

So guys, what do you think about my approach and do you have any better approaches???

Thanks for your help,
E.

Comment: please write any code ... like cellForRowAtIndexPath and connectionDidFinishLoading

Comment: Post your code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to tag and loop through your cells to find matches won't work because of UITableViewCell reuse. There are only as many cells in memory as you can see on screen, and these cells get recycled to display different data. Therefore, you won't be able to create a tag for each row in your table view, because the table view is only using a handful of cells.

What you should do instead is create a `UITableViewCell` subclass that knows how to asynchronously download and display in the image itself. Using the [UIImageView category from AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit+AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h) is perfect for doing something like this, instead of having to manage the URL connection yourself. Import this category in your cell subclass, and write a method that calls `setImageWithURL:` to asynchronously download and display the image. Also, make sure to overload the UITableViewCell method `prepareForReuse`, in which you should call `cancelImageRequestOperation` on your image view. This is so the request to download the image is cancelled if the cell is reused before the download is complete.

Comment: This approach may work for a number of use cases where the images are small and where there are not many rows in the table - but it's by far not "perfect". In fact, if the table has a large number of rows, and the user is scrolling quickly through it, you initiate a perfect DOS attack agianst the server ;).  In practice you almost always need a more sophisticated solution. One can alleviate this problem with a network queue whose maximum number of concurrent requests is limited, but it's not optimal as well.

Comment: The faster the user scrolls, the sooner is each cell is reused and the request is cancelled. Queueing would definitely help fewer requests be made, but I think with that along with caching keeps this from being anything like a perfect DOS attack, especially when we're talking about Facebook

Comment: Take it with a grain of salt ;)  But imagine the following contrived example: the user scrolls as fast as required to just cancel each request which has been already started. We can safely assume the server's task to respond with an image isn't cancelable due to the canceled connection. So, the server sends that image. Suppose, it's possible to start and cancel 100 requests per second (seems doable to me). On the client side the responses are not cached in the URL cache (but possibly on a proxy). Sending 100 images per second isn't that a light task for a server. Multiply this with N users ;)